# How to cleanup kubernetes configMaps that are no longer used by pods

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, configmap

We use kustomize to create a unique configMap for our Deployments whenever a new change to configMap data is made.   We now are left with a number of old configMaps which are no longer in use by any Pods - I can find them in Rancher, but that's a pain - how can I automate cleaning up those configMaps that are no longer used by any Pods?

I've tried running:  `kubectl get configmaps --namespace mynamespace --output=json`

I was hoping to see a reverse reference to the Pod that's using it - but I can't find the right info in there.

Comment: grep every configmap name thru all pod yamls? :)

Comment: Also if you add an index/timestamp to a configmap you could sort them and delete all except the 3 latest for example

Answer (score 5):

If your configmaps can be identified using a label, you can just use the [--prune](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/declarative-config/#alternative-kubectl-apply-f-directory-prune-l-your-label) flag to get rid of the dangling resources. If you'd add it to your deployment pipelines the orphaned resources should slowly be cleaned from the cluster.

See this [comment](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/issues/876#issuecomment-472600524) for how people are using this in conjunction with kustomize.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this tool to discover the unused configmaps in your cluster and delete them.
https://github.com/yonahd/orphaned-configmaps